# "ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_policy" after booting Phoenix OS for Nexus 7 2013 Wi-Fi on LTE device

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, nexus-7, phoenix-os

I was trying to boot Nexus 7 2013 Wi-Fi (flo) ROM on the LTE (deb) device. The ROM is Phoenix OS. I'm stuck waiting for service `media.audio_policy`.

```
01-01 20:04:22.973   1041   1235 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
01-01 20:04:22.973   1041   1235 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
01-01 20:04:22.974   1041   1235 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
01-01 20:04:22.974   1041   1235 W AudioSystem: AudioPolicyService not published, waiting...
```

<sup>[Screenshot of logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rof1i.png)</sup>

The LCD itself sometimes shows "Starting Apps", other times it just shows boot animation.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The ROM finally booted.

What I did : I replaced `/system/lib/audio*.so` with file from working ROM (in my case, LineageOS ROM).